# Can't position a div exactly over another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to write a general Javascript function that will take the ID of an element on a web page and place a `div` exactly over the top of it. This is to hold an Ajax busy indicator.

I tried the following...

```
function showAjax(el) {
  var pos = $("#" + el).position();
  var width = $("#" + el).outerWidth();
  var height = $("#" + el).outerHeight();
  var ajax = $('<div id="ajaxBusy"></div>');
  ajax.css("top", pos.top);
  ajax.css("left", pos.left);
  ajax.css("width", width);
  ajax.css("height", height);
  ajax.insertAfter("#" + el);
}
```

However, this positioned the new element too high and to the left, by the size of the margin. So if the top margin of the element passed in was 10px, the created element would be 10px too high on the page.

I tried to get around this by calculating the margins and adding them on...

```
function showAjax(el) {
  var pos = $("#" + el).position();
  var width = $("#" + el).outerWidth();
  var height = $("#" + el).outerHeight();
  var marginL = $("#" + el).css("margin-left").replace("px", "");
  var marginT = $("#" + el).css("margin-top").replace("px", "");
  var ajax = $('<div id="ajaxBusy"></div>');
  var left = pos.left + marginL;
  var top = pos.top + marginT;
  ajax.css("top", pos.top + marginT);
  ajax.css("left", pos.left + marginL);
  ajax.css("width", width);
  ajax.css("height", height);
  ajax.insertAfter("#" + el);
}
```

However, this placed it in completely the wrong position altogether.

Anyone able to explain what I should be doing? I don't have any CSS set yet, so that's not affecting things, and I'm using an ordinary `div` tag for the element passed to the function.

Comment: `.position()` returns the position *relative to the offset parent*. Maybe you want to use `.offset()` which, in turn, gives you the offset relative to the document. If that works better, you might want to add the ajaxBusy element directly to body

Comment: what you have now seems to work for me... https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/XgdZeR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `.appendTo` here which seems to have the desired results while using innerWidth and innerHeight without additional margin requirements. Making sure the parent div is set to `position:relative;`

```js
function showAjax(el) {

  var width = $("#" + el).innerWidth();
  var height = $("#" + el).innerHeight();
  var ajax = $('<div id="ajaxBusy" class="div2"></div>');
  ajax.css("width", width);
  ajax.css("height", height);
  ajax.appendTo("#" + el);
}
```

```css
 .div1 {
  border:1px dotted #ddd;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}

.div2 {
  border:1px dotted #000;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="div1" id="div1" onclick="showAjax('div1');"></div>
```

Comment: That's great, thank. I didn't think of positioning the busy indicator inside the container. Makes it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, first, set css-class of your div to the `busy`. Then, Add a div with the class `overlay` as a child of your div. the follwoing css are also should be added to your page (just `busy` and `overlay` classes).
the following code, shows how the css works:

```css
div{
 display:block;
 background-color:red;
 min-height:50px;
 margin:10px;
}

.busy{
 position:relative;
}

.overlay{
 position:absolute;
 margin:0px;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background-color:blue;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 opacity:.5;
 z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<div>div-1</div>
<div class="busy">
 <div class="overlay"></div>
 div-2
</div>
<div>div-3</div>
```